# IPython interactive widget is not updating plotly when downloaded as html

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, plotly

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and trying to create an interactive plot. I really like how simple the `ipywidgets.interactive` is to use and having the ability to lay things out in `VBox` or `HBox`. The problem I'm having is once I download as html the `ipywidgets.interactive` is not updating my plot.

Here is what I have:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

py.init_notebook_mode()

xs = np.linspace(0,6,100)
ys = np.sin(xs)

scatter = go.Scatter(
    x = xs,
    y = ys
)

data = [scatter]
layout = go.Layout(title='test')

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
slider = widgets.FloatRangeSlider(
    min=1,
    max=6,
    step=.1,
    description='desc'
)

def update_b(b):
    fig.data[0].y = np.sin(xs+b)

vb = widgets.VBox((fig, interactive(update_b, b=(1, 6, .1))))
vb.layout.align_items='center'
# This displays it and allows it to be interactive, but only when I have it as .ipynb, 
# not when I download as html
display(vb)
```

The way I am saving as html is:
1. `Widgets` > `Save Notebook Widget State`
2. From cmd: `jupyter nbconvert --to html test_plot.ipynb`

I have also done the following to enable the `widget extension`:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: ok
```

After everything this is what I get:
[image]

The thing is the slider is movable but it does not update the graph. The graph is also able to be manipulated through zoom, etc. like normal with plotly. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the way I've used `interactive`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not work this way, the function that links the slider with the plot is written in python and executes in the python kernel, so when you convert to a static html this function does not exist anymore.

I am not aware of some kind of python to javascript translator that allows these kind of functions to run without a python kernel, although plotly's [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) seems to be doing something in this line ([see this issue](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/266)). If you can put up a server you can use [Voila](https://github.com/QuantStack/voila) or something similar to make the notebook look like a web page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not using plotly, however, try adding some line magic, like "widget" which makes the graph interactive...

```
%matplotlib widget
%matplotlib widget
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    fig.canvas.draw()

interact(update);
```

[screenshot of notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJTKx.png)